# Por qué no funciona nextElementSibling en el gadget Cuadro HTML de Google Sites

Tags: javascript, dom, google-sites

En SO en inglés me encontré [JavaScript accordion on Google Sites (classic)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44310096/1595451). Luego de trastear me dí cuenta que `nextElementSibling` no funciona en el gadget Cuadro HTML pero `nextSibling` sí.

En el foro oficial de Google Sites, [he preguntado](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/-4r7kjEaQVE) por qué no funciona. Al momento Steegle un antiguo Colaborador Principal, se ha limitado a decir que no todo el código funciona como uno esperaría.

Según entiendo el gadget Cuadro HTML hace uso de [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) para esterilizar el código huésped y sé que cosas como el llamar archivos externos con excepción de las librerías jQuery alojadas en Google está bloqueado.

`nextElementSibling` me parece unan propiedad inocua del HTML DOM y pienso que que debería permitirse su uso. ¿Estoy en lo correcto o estoy perdiendo algo de vista?

**Referencias**

- [Crear diseños de página o gadget personalizados](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=es)

Comment: Disculpa pero, `trastear` querrás decir: ¿testear o intentar?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Sí. En algunas comunidades como esta algunos usuarios lo usan, de hecho, creo haberlo leído en esta hoy mismo y "se me pegó".